# Why did Godel use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to encode sequences of numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, incompleteness

Godel's Beta trick of encoding sequences of numbers to a single number uses the Chinese Remainder theorem (which uses the MOD operator) to essentially construct a primitive integer array.

Why would he use this somewhat clumsy approach instead of the far easier and vastly more efficient method using the MOD and DIV operators?

Comment: What exactly is "the far easier and vastly more efficient method using the MOD and DIV operators?"

Comment: A friend of mine has claimed that using sets of finite rank rather than using finite cardinal numbers makes it possible to avoid any need to use the Chinese remainder theorem. But I know nothing of the details.

Comment: @NoahSchweber -  its a pretty straight forward task to encode any length sequence of integers of any given size using MOD and DIV operations and to read/write those values as well as determine sequence length in O(1) time.

Comment: @CShreve Great, and once you show me the details of how to implement that in the specific limited language of first-order arithmetic (rather than just "it's a pretty straightforward task") I may or may not agree that it is simpler than using the $\beta$-function in this context.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, that's true. Having exponentiation as primitive also does this. The role of the CRT is very specific to the precise setting of first-order arithmetic without exponentiation as primitive; there are lots of other settings where things are smoother (and FWIW when teaching GIT I use such settings instead).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I added what I suspect is the intended vastly more efficient method to my answer.

Comment: @CShreve Do my and Misha's answers address your question?

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on Misha's answer, remember that Godel is trying to produce a *first-order formula* in a specific language, and this is an extremely limited syntax. An algorithm which is intuitively simple may nonetheless be quite tedious to "encapsulate" in a formula of this type. By contrast, the $\beta$-function approach has no such difficulties (even though the $\beta$ function itself is a bit odd).

Now you might respond that having a clear algorithm should be a satisfying proxy for a specific first-order formula, but that's a very modern perspective and takes a lot for granted: that type of algorithm/formula conflation is only justified by a general theory of algorithms which postdates Godel (Turing machines were introduced in $1936$ but incompleteness is $1931$) ... and moreover includes the fact that addition and multiplication alone are enough to "implement algorithms in a first-order way" (in the appropriate sense).

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency was not a concern, because nobody was ever going to do concrete calculations with the function. Gödel's $\beta$ function
$$
   \beta(x,y,z) = x \bmod (1 + y + yz)
$$
has the advantage of being *easier to describe* than any efficient scheme. It requires only one even slightly unusual arithmetic operation (mod), and it has a very short definition.

Compare this to the definition he **didn't** make of
$$
   \beta(x,y,z) = \left\lfloor\frac{x}{y^z}\right\rfloor \bmod y
$$
which involves exponents and integer division. Its advantage is that the numbers $x$ and $y$ will be smaller to encode a particular sequence... but so what?

Comment: Not to mention that figuring out how to define exponentiation using just addition and multiplication *in a first-order way* is nontrivial ... and accomplished by Godel's $\beta$-function.